# Как сверстать такой выпадающий список?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, очень срочно нужно сверстать такой выпадающий список с картинками и вот таким оформлением. Никак не пойму, как это сделать. Нужно добавить картинку, как-то позиционировать внутри этого списка текст, background поставить #fff, а border 1px solid #000.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/953915

Answer (score 4):

Если следовать меткам в вопросе ([html](/questions/tagged/html)[css](/questions/tagged/css)), то один из способов обойтись без скриптов может быть таким:

```css
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px grey;
}
.select::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9em;
  right: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 0.7em;
  width: 0.7em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 grey;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.select input {
  display: none;
}

.color {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.select:hover .color {
  min-height: 3em;
  height: auto;
}
.select input:checked+.color {
  z-index: 1;
  order: -1;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px grey;
}
.select input:not(:checked)+.color:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.color img {
  margin: 0.5em 1em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 3em;
}

.select .placehold {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  order: -1;
  min-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px grey;
}
.select input:checked~.placehold {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="1" id="color01">
  <label for="color01" class="color">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c937j.jpg" alt="" style="filter: hue-rotate(60deg) saturate(300%)">
    <span class="color-title">All green</span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="2" id="color02">
  <label for="color02" class="color">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c937j.jpg" alt="" style="filter: hue-rotate(120deg) saturate(300%)">
    <span class="color-title">All blue</span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="3" id="color03">
  <label for="color03" class="color">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c937j.jpg" alt="" style="filter: hue-rotate(260deg) saturate(300%)">
    <span class="color-title">All pink</span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="4" id="color04">
  <label for="color04" class="color">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c937j.jpg" alt="" style="filter: hue-rotate(350deg) saturate(700%)">
    <span class="color-title">All mustard</span>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="5" id="color05">
  <label for="color05" class="color">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/c937j.jpg" alt="" style="filter: hue-rotate(300deg) saturate(700%)">
    <span class="color-title">All red</span>
  </label>
  <div class="placehold">Choose color</div>
</div>
```

Плюс этого подхода - при отправке формы, сохраняется обычный доступ к `<input>`-ам.

Минус данной реализации - отсутствие прокрутки списка. Таким образом, добавление большого количества пунктов (например, более 10) затруднительно. Хотя, здесь всё зависит от дизайна и разрешений экранов.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector(".drop").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e = event.target.closest(".drop-item").innerHTML;
  document.querySelector(".colors").innerHTML = e;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.parent {
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 80px;
}

.drop {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 320px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.14s ease;
}

.parent:hover {
  height: auto;
}

.parent:hover .drop {
  visibility: visible;
}

.colors {
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.colors .drop-item {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.drop-item {
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 5px 0 20px;
}

.drop-item:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.drop-item_flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.drop-item_flex img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="colors">
    <span>Choose color</span>
  </div>

  <div class="drop">

    <div class="drop-item flex1">
      <div class="drop-item_flex flex1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x60/ff0" alt="">
        <span>All Green1</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="drop-item flex2">
      <div class="drop-item_flex">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x60/00f" alt="">
        <span>All Green2</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="drop-item flex3">
      <div class="drop-item_flex">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x60/0f0" alt="">
        <span>All Green3</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="drop-item flex4">
      <div class="drop-item_flex">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x60/000" alt="">
        <span>All Green4</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="drop-item flex5">
      <div class="drop-item_flex">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x60/ffa" alt="">
        <span>All Green5</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="drop-item  flex6">
      <div class="drop-item_flex">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x60/fcf" alt="">
        <span>All Green6</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="drop-item flex7">
      <div class="drop-item_flex ">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x60/ccf" alt="">
        <span>All Green7</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- drop -->
</div>
<!-- parent-->

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на один из элементов в списке - оставался только он, вместо "Choose color"?)

Comment: @Dikkkey это либо javascript либо использовать что то другое ..